# What glue to stick polycarbonate and glass together?

Tags: adhesive, glass

I am searching for strong glue that

1. Bonds polycarbonate to glass
2. Is cold and hot weather resistant (approximately -50 to 50)
3. Is transparent
   Optional: Would ideally bond glass if it was broken like PVB

I already searched that some blends of silicone and polyurethane adhesives are used to bond those two together, but I don't know about the cold weather resistance.

Comment: Interestingly, you might get some good answers to this on the photography stack exchange too, since gluing lenses in a transparent way that's durable in extreme environments is done all the time in professional camera lenses.

Comment: You sometimes get good ideas and answers when you *actually describe the problem you are trying to solve*, rather than restricting all input by your narrow description of solution parameters. There are ancient parables about problem solving by drawing on the imagination, intelligence, resources, and skills of all those in the village; we don't know your problem.

Comment: The different coefficients of thermal expansion (glass *.vs.* plastic) will be a problem over that temperature range.

Answer (score 1):

Readily available products will include clear epoxies and marine grade silicone adhesives

Auto/Marine silicone sealant is typically rated to -40F, up to 350F and is quite clear between 2 pieces of glass, I do not know how the solvent will react with the PC in terms of changing the clarity of the surface. It dries like a high durometer rubber and can assist in noise/vibration damping from one surface to the next. These take at least a day to cure.

30-minute epoxies harden solid, but have a lower temp range, around -60F to 180F. They get HOT when they cure, which can lead to warping of certain plastics, but when bonded to glass this should not be a problem.

Optically clear lens adhesives are based on epoxy or acrylate and have a slightly more narrow range of temperatures, usally -40 to 150F. They are solvent free and are thus cured rapidly using ultraviolet light or heating (or both together). The lack of solvent should mean no change in surface clarity of the PC.

Comment: There are some silicones that are safe on polycarbonate. and many that are not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful website for adhesives usage. It suggests a few options for sticking plastic to glass:

https://www.thistothat.com/cgi-bin/glue.cgi?lang=en&this=Glass&that=Plastic

> **Glass to Plastic**
>
> For the strongest, fastest, and most invisible bond we recommend:
> Loctite Impruv
>
> If Loctite is not available in your area, or you live in Alaska in the winter where there is no available UV light, we recommend:
> Household Goop
> For a non-toxic but not so strong alternative we recommend:
> Weldbond
> Hot Glue"